# JavaFx не запускается приложение, проблема с именем пользователя

Tags: java, windows, javafx

Код класса, в котором происходит ошибка:

```
    package ru.simplemc.launcher;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.StageStyle;

import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;

import static ru.simplemc.launcher.Constants.parent;
import static ru.simplemc.launcher.Constants.primaryStage;
import static ru.simplemc.launcher.FrameController.getSavedThemeCode;
import static ru.simplemc.launcher.Settings.frameSize;
import static ru.simplemc.launcher.utils.Utils.checkForbiddenArguments;
import static ru.simplemc.launcher.utils.Utils.loadFonts;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {

        checkForbiddenArguments();

        System.setProperty("java.net.preferIPv4Stack", "true");
        System.setProperty("prism.lcdtext", "false");
        System.setProperty("file.encoding", "UTF-8");
        System.setProperty("glass.accessible.force", "false");

        Field charset = Charset.class.getDeclaredField("defaultCharset");
        charset.setAccessible(true);
        charset.set(null, null);

        loadFonts();

        parent = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/assets/fxml/Frame.fxml"));
        parent.getStylesheets().add("/assets/fxml/themes/theme_" + getSavedThemeCode() + ".css");

        Scene scene = new Scene(parent, frameSize[0], frameSize[1]);
        scene.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT);

        primaryStage = stage;
        primaryStage.getIcons().add(new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/assets/icons/icon.png")));
        primaryStage.setResizable(false);
        primaryStage.setTitle("SimpleMinecraft.Ru - Лаунчер");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Пользователь запускает приложение, но из-за ! в имени пользователя оно не запускается. windows 10.

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$1(LauncherImpl.java:182)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users (Отказано в доступе)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile.getJarFile(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarFileFactory.get(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URL.openStream(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2440)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3214)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3175)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3148)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3124)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3104)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3097)
        at simplemc.m.start(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$8(LauncherImpl.java:863)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$7(PlatformImpl.java:326)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$5(PlatformImpl.java:295)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$6(PlatformImpl.java:294)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$4(WinApplication.java:186)
        ... 1 more
```

Comment: Мне кажется, причина в этом C:\Users (Отказано в доступе)

Comment: Или у вас с ошибками идёт присвоение parent -> fxml ->controller